# How to make a layout, where the 3rd child is full width?

Tags: css, flexbox

Is it possible to make the following layout just with Flexbox? Or what would be the recommended way?

[image: example layout of images]

Example code (getting images from an API):

```
<div class="container">
 {images.map(image => {
   return(
       <div class="item">
          <img src={image.thumbnail} />
       </div>
   );
 })}
</div>
```

Example CSS:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

img:nth-child(3) {
   flex: 1 100%;
}
```

Comment: Do these boxes have ordering or not? Do you need to arrange them or how is that done?

Comment: Just in a random order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set `flex-basis: 100%` to your third flex item

An additional rule setting the `img` to `width: 100%` will make them size properly.

*Also, for best cross browser support, keep the wrapper around each `img`*

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.item {
  background: lightgray;
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 10px);
  margin: 5px;
}

.item:nth-child(3) {
  flex-basis: calc(100% - 10px);
}

.item img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
       <div class="item">
          <img src='http://placehold.it/300x100' />
       </div>
       <div class="item">
          <img src='http://placehold.it/300x100' />
       </div>
       <div class="item">
          <img src='http://placehold.it/300x100' />
       </div>
       <div class="item">
          <img src='http://placehold.it/300x100' />
       </div>
       <div class="item">
          <img src='http://placehold.it/300x100' />
       </div>
       <div class="item">
          <img src='http://placehold.it/300x100' />
       </div>
       <div class="item">
          <img src='http://placehold.it/300x100' />
       </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe i don't understand correctly what you want, but here it is :

see [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qqqgncm0/) or snippet below

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
img {
  height:auto;
  flex:1 50%;

}
img:nth-child(3) {
   flex: 1 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example you're doing img:nth-child(3) but your images are wrapped with an div. So your images are not the flex childs. Here is a possible solution to your problem:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container div{
  width: 50%;
  /* just for demonstration, not needed: */
  text-align:center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 2px solid white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container div:nth-child(3) {
   width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS works, you just need an additional rule for the other images to get two each into the other rows, plus you can leave out the wrapping DIVs (if that's not possible/desired, just apply the same rules to the DIVs instead and set all image widths to 100%):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
img {
box-sizing: border-box;
width: 50%;
padding: 10px;
}
img:nth-child(3) {
   flex: 1 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<img src="http://placehold.it/500x200/ed8">
<img src="http://placehold.it/500x200/ed8">
<img src="http://placehold.it/500x200/ed8">
<img src="http://placehold.it/500x200/ed8">
<img src="http://placehold.it/500x200/ed8">
<img src="http://placehold.it/500x200/ed8">
<img src="http://placehold.it/500x200/ed8">
<img src="http://placehold.it/500x200/ed8">
</div>
```